# Unity and vuforia script errors

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, vuforia

I have this problem in this script.

```
using UnityEngine;
using Vuforia;

public class TouchInput_1 : MonoBehaviour, ITrackableEventHandler
{
    private TrackableBehaviour mTrackableBehaviour;
    public GameObject temploMaiaObject; // Reference to the 3D object named "Templo_Maia"
    private AudioSource audioSource;
    private bool isPlaying = false;

    void Start()
    {
        audioSource = temploMaiaObject.GetComponent<AudioSource>();

        // Register this script to trackable event handler
        mTrackableBehaviour = GetComponent<TrackableBehaviour>();
        if (mTrackableBehaviour)
        {
            mTrackableBehaviour.RegisterTrackableEventHandler(this);
        }
    }

    void OnDestroy()
    {
        // Unregister this script from trackable event handler
        if (mTrackableBehaviour)
        {
            mTrackableBehaviour.UnregisterTrackableEventHandler(this);
        }
    }

    public void OnTrackableStateChanged(TrackableBehaviour.Status previousStatus, TrackableBehaviour.Status newStatus)
    {
        if (newStatus == TrackableBehaviour.Status.DETECTED ||
            newStatus == TrackableBehaviour.Status.TRACKED ||
            newStatus == TrackableBehaviour.Status.EXTENDED_TRACKED)
        {
            // Target is detected and being tracked
            Debug.Log("Target is detected!");

            // Enable touch input
            enabled = true;
        }
        else
        {
            // Target is lost or not being tracked
            Debug.Log("Target is lost!");

            // Disable touch input
            enabled = false;

            // Pause audio playback
            if (isPlaying)
            {
```

detected errors

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   CS0246  The type or namespace name 'ITrackableEventHandler' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)    Assembly-CSharp M:\IS MOTION PROJECT\PROJETO\AR\Projeto_3D\Projeto_02\Assets\TouchInput_1.cs    4   Active
Error   CS1513  } expected  Assembly-CSharp M:\IS MOTION PROJECT\PROJETO\AR\Projeto_3D\Projeto_02\Assets\TouchInput_1.cs    54  Active
Error   CS1513  } expected  Assembly-CSharp M:\IS MOTION PROJECT\PROJETO\AR\Projeto_3D\Projeto_02\Assets\TouchInput_1.cs    54  Active
Error   CS1513  } expected  Assembly-CSharp M:\IS MOTION PROJECT\PROJETO\AR\Projeto_3D\Projeto_02\Assets\TouchInput_1.cs    54  Active
Error   CS1513  } expected  Assembly-CSharp M:\IS MOTION PROJECT\PROJETO\AR\Projeto_3D\Projeto_02\Assets\TouchInput_1.cs    54  Active
Error   CS0246  The type or namespace name 'TrackableBehaviour' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)    Assembly-CSharp M:\IS MOTION PROJECT\PROJETO\AR\Projeto_3D\Projeto_02\Assets\TouchInput_1.cs    6   Active
Error   CS0246  The type or namespace name 'TrackableBehaviour' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)    Assembly-CSharp M:\IS MOTION PROJECT\PROJETO\AR\Projeto_3D\Projeto_02\Assets\TouchInput_1.cs    32  Active
Error   CS0246  The type or namespace name 'TrackableBehaviour' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)    Assembly-CSharp M:\IS MOTION PROJECT\PROJETO\AR\Projeto_3D\Projeto_02\Assets\TouchInput_1.cs    32  Active
Error   CS0246  The type or namespace name 'TrackableBehaviour' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)    Assembly-CSharp M:\IS MOTION PROJECT\PROJETO\AR\Projeto_3D\Projeto_02\Assets\TouchInput_1.cs    16  Active
Error   CS0103  The name 'TrackableBehaviour' does not exist in the current context Assembly-CSharp M:\IS MOTION PROJECT\PROJETO\AR\Projeto_3D\Projeto_02\Assets\TouchInput_1.cs    34  Active
Error   CS0103  The name 'TrackableBehaviour' does not exist in the current context Assembly-CSharp M:\IS MOTION PROJECT\PROJETO\AR\Projeto_3D\Projeto_02\Assets\TouchInput_1.cs    35  Active
Error   CS0103  The name 'TrackableBehaviour' does not exist in the current context Assembly-CSharp M:\IS MOTION PROJECT\PROJETO\AR\Projeto_3D\Projeto_02\Assets\TouchInput_1.cs    36  Active

I want the 3D element linked to the Image Target to be able to control playing and pausing an audio source linked to it via touch screen.

Comment: check out the answer i posted here, it might give you a hint with  ITrackableEventHandler issue: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75814175/the-itrackableeventhandler-is-not-working/76777352#76777352

Answer (score 0):

You getting  an error: The type or namespace name 'ITrackableEventHandler' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?).

this used to work with the older version of vuforia but with the newer vuforia engine all you have to do is to directly register an Observer-specific status changed event and use it to evaluate the current status directly as below:

```
using UnityEngine;
using Vuforia;

public class TouchInput_1 : MonoBehaviour
{
    private TrackableBehaviour mTrackableBehaviour;

    // Reference to the 3D object named "Templo_Maia"
    public GameObject temploMaiaObject; 

    private AudioSource audioSource;
    private bool isPlaying = false;

    ObserverBehaviour modelTargetBehaviour;

    void Start()
    {
        audioSource = temploMaiaObject.GetComponent<AudioSource>();

        // Register this script to trackable event handler
        modelTargetBehaviour = temploMaiaObject.GetComponent<ObserverBehaviour>();
    }

    void OnDestroy()
    {
       //
    }

   void OnTargetStatusChanged(ObserverBehaviour observerbehavour, TargetStatus status)
 {

    if (status.Status == Status.TRACKED && status.StatusInfo == StatusInfo.NORMAL)
    {
        // ...
    } else{
       // ...
}

}
...
...
...

}
```

I hope that helps.