# The ITrackableEventHandler is not working

Tags: vuforia

> Hello, I am using an old script that uses ITrackableEventHandler. But with the newer version of Vuforia, it has been depreciated. I'm not sure what is the replacement.

both ITrackableEventHandler and TrackableBehaviour  are giving error.

This is the error:

Assets\IoT.cs(7,35): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'ITrackableEventHandler' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

``

> using UnityEngine;
> using UnityEngine.UI;
> using System.Collections;
> using Vuforia;
> //using System.IO.Ports;
>
> public class IoT : MonoBehaviour, ITrackableEventHandler
> {
> public GameObject imageTarget;
> private TrackableBehaviour mTrackableBehaviour;
> private bool targetFound = false;
> public GameObject hide;
> ``

not sure what to do

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you really want to do with ITrackableEventHandler, but just as you mentioned above I think it doesn't work with the recent vuforia Engine.

With the new vuforia engine (10.15.4 or above).. all you need to do is to directly register an Observer-specific status changed event and use it to evaluate the current status directly as below:

```
ObserverBehaviour modelTargetBehaviour;

void Start()
{
    modelTargetBehaviour.OnTargetStatusChanged += OnTargetStatusChanged;
}
void OnTargetStatusChanged(ObserverBehaviour observerbehavour, TargetStatus status)
{
    if (status.Status == Status.TRACKED && status.StatusInfo == StatusInfo.NORMAL)
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

For more info please about: attaching content to a target, error handling or creating an observer please check out the vuforia library documentation: https://library.vuforia.com/getting-started/vuforia-engine-api-unity.

I hope this helps. Best of luck.